# Browsers which do not support HTML <table> tag?

Tags: html, html-table

I'm working on ASP.NET MVC3. I was told by my senior to remove all the `<table></table>` tags in my View and use `<div>` tags for displaying tabular content because some browsers do not support this tag! I searched on Google, but I couldn't find any such browser. Are there really any browsers that do not support the `<table>` tag?

Comment: You simply ask your senior to tell you at least name of one browser that doesn't support table tag.

Comment: I think what he referers to is that the layout is not consistent in all bowsers with <table>. Using <div> will make styling and layout much easier.

Comment: Well, there is Lynx... which intentionally doesn't implement them when used for layout (it's feature, deal with it...). It seems to depend this on existence of <caption> tag, but please... don't force Lynx to view table layout unless it's actually tabular data. Many other browser used for accessibility also ignore tables unless they're sure those aren't used for layout purposes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `<div>` and `<table>` debutted in [HTML 3](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/Contents.html) that is Spring '95.

Good luck finding a browser that supports `<div>` and not `<table>`.

If you did find a browser that didn't support tables (You might need a copy of [Windows 95](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_95)).

**Introducing [HTML 2](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/L2index.html)**

Here is a list of tags :-)

A, ADDRESS, B, BASE, BLOCKQUOTE, BODY, BR, CITE, CODE, DD, DIR, DL, DT, EM, FORM, H1, H2, H3, H4, H5, H6, HEAD, HR, HTML, I, IMG, INPUT, ISINDEX, KBD, LI, LINK, LISTING, MENU, META, NEXTID, OL, OPTION, P, PLAINTEXT, PRE, SAMP, SELECT, STRONG, TEXTAREA, TITLE, TT, UL, VAR, XMP,

Answer (score 3):

`<table>` is one of the basic constructs of HTML and is rendered by all browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: Noooooooooooooooooo.

Real answer: Because of IE 6 and its complete support for `<table>`s, it is probably the *best* supported tag anywhere, including in email clients.

Answer (score 2):

[Tables are part of the HTML 4 standard.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html)  Any browser that doesn't support HTML 4 standards (if such a browser even exists) is probably not a browser worth supporting.

Answer (score 2):

Either you've misunderstood them, they've misunderstood something or they haven't any idea what they are talking about.

My assumption is what they mean is that the View will create the `table` tags and it's children so you don't have to explicitly declare them your self.

Literally every browser and their mother supports the `table` tag.

Answer (score 2):

There are (HTML 2 didn't have a table element and browsers were written when it came out) but not that you have to worry about.

For tabular data, a table is the correct semantic element. The element has been in HTML for several stable versions. Support is not something you need to worry about.

You should, however, make use of `summary`, `scope` and `<th>` to make it easier for non-graphical browsers / screen readers to express the table semantics to readers.

(For non-tabular data, you shouldn't use a table, but your question says that isn't the type of data being discussed here).

Answer (score 1):

Either your senior is confused or you mis-heard him. The idea is that tables should not be used for *layout*; instead you should use divs styled with css.

http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/everything.html

But for tabular content, tables are perfect. *That's what they're for*.

There are no real browsers that don't support tables. There may be some rare text-only browsers out there, but they can't display any layout at all, and that's really your audience.

Answer (score 1):

All browsers used nowadays recognize table markup. This does not mean that they all render `table` elements as formatted in a tabular manner. Speech-based or Braille browsers apparently *cannot* do that. Character cell browsers such as Lynx *could* do that, with severe limitations, but mostly won’t try.

Speech-based browsers may give the user the option of accessing a table cell by its row and column headers, by “coordinates” so to say, or alternatively to listen to them sequentially. Lynx starts each table row in a new line but doesn’t really try to align the cell contents in columns.

This does not mean that it would be a good or even acceptable idea to use `div` elements instead of table markup for tabular data. On the contrary, it would destroy the accessibility that properly marked-up tables provide.

If the advice was misheard and it was really about using `div` elements instead of table markup for **other than** tabular data, then it makes much, much more sense. Not everyone would sign it, though, when given as unqualified and absolute rule.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is over a year old, but also that it is still open. If this is still an item of issue, your senior may be referring to the deprecated use of table element attributes like "bgcolor" and "align" in HTML5 specification, tables will very much be usable - just encouraged to have attribute properties separated in css. If perhaps there may have been confusion about displaying "table-like" properties, and which browsers support (ie. div display:table-cell) - you're mainly looking at no support for IE 7.0 and below, mainly for the other majors, globally supported. See caniuse.com.