# Do any current mobile browsers NOT support tables?

Tags: mobile, browser, html-table

I mean, basic, simple support of the `<table>` tag, to display tabular data with multiple rows and columns. Support for styling is not important for this particular issue.

I have just been told that some "base web" browsers do not support tables, for a product launched in the U.S. only. That means the lowest common denominator for featurephones. They do have to have a browser, though.

However, I have been designing for mobile forever and have never really heard of this. Even 5 years ago I only was aware that some had poor support, so too many lines or too much nesting would blow them up, but every browser in our market supported tables. I think cHTML might not have, but that's not something we'll encounter here, now.

I have access to a bunch of devices, and cannot find a lack of support on: Obigo, UC Web (J2ME), Access (v3) or the S40 browser.

Not to mention of course all the smartphone platforms.

Comment: In case someone else mentions it, yes I am aware of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9307191/browsers-which-do-not-support-html-table-tag I saw no mobile answers. Also: I am not talking about formatting, but for display of tabular data as a part of an otherwise adequately-formatted page.